# What is the Spring 5 JDBC approach when nativeJdbcExtractor is needed?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

I have just upgraded Spring/SpringBoot dependencies and noticed that class JdbcTemplate does not have property "nativeJdbcExtractor" any more.

I was able to find the details and background:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14670

However I was not able to find the replacement configuration. I use commons-dbcp library and Spring classes like **SimpleJdbcCall** etc. I never deal with low level JDBC API, however if the vendor code needs its real Connection type (Oracle) the **nativeJdbcExtractor** settings ensured it will get it somewhere deep in Spring JDBC code (not my app. code). I´m not sure how I can address this by calling **connection.unwrap()** if I need Spring API to handle this automatically as it did it in past.

*java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection*

Is that hidden somewhere in DataSource configuration? I have upgraded from commons-dbcp 1.4 to commons-dbcp2 but cannot find anything useful so far (BasicDataSource).

**Update:** Following thread is relevant but I cannot digest the answer I´m looking for since the Connection object is obtained within JdbcTemplate class and thus out of my control.

[replacement for jdbc.support.nativejdbc remove in Spring 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397238/replacement-for-jdbc-support-nativejdbc-remove-in-spring-5)

**Update #2 - Stack Trace**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
at oracle.sql.TypeDescriptor.setPhysicalConnectionOf(TypeDescriptor.java:832)
at oracle.sql.TypeDescriptor.<init>(TypeDescriptor.java:586)
at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.<init>(ArrayDescriptor.java:224)
at org.springframework.data.jdbc.support.oracle.SqlArrayValue.createTypeValue(SqlArrayValue.java:90)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.AbstractSqlTypeValue.setTypeValue(AbstractSqlTypeValue.java:60)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:293)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:232)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:147)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.CallableStatementCreatorFactory$CallableStatementCreatorImpl.createCallableStatement(CallableStatementCreatorFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1048)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1104)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:414)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:397)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:193)
```

**Update #3 - the code doing the cast (Oracle JDBC)**

```
    public void setPhysicalConnectionOf(Connection var1) {
    this.connection = ((oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection)var1).physicalConnectionWithin();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**New:**

It looks like you're using `org.springframework.data.jdbc.support.oracle.SqlArrayValue` from `spring-data-jdbc-ext`. The bug is there and the unwrapping should happen there.

Something like the following (untested)

```
protected Object createTypeValue(Connection conn, int sqlType, String typeName)
        throws SQLException { 
    return conn.unwrap(OracleConnection.class).createArray(typeName, values);
}
```

Regarding the JDBC driver:

You are using Java 8 or later since Spring 5 requires Java 8. Therefore you should use ojdbc8 (8 means Java 8). I strongly recommend using the latest 12.2.0.1 driver from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/downloads/index.html.

If you check the driver interoperability matrix from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_02 you will see that this diver also works with older databases.

**Old/Outdated:**

In your code that performs the cast instead of casting call `#unwrap`. So instead of

```
OracleConnection oracleConnection = (OracleConnection) connection;
```

call

```
OracleConnection oracleConnection = connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
```

In the stack trace you see who is doing the cast, this will be in your code because `SimpleJdbcCall` and friends don't case to `OracleConnection`. The issue is not in `JdbcTemplate` but your code doing the cast.

Comment: Thanks - But that is what is confusing for me - I have done that and I checked the stacktrace and saw the casting is NOT in my code, which I was not surprised as I never deal with raw Connection type. Please take a look at the stacktrace - you can see it is in JDBC driver code called by Spring code ... and this works well if "nativeJdbcExtractor" property can be used, but does not work with Spring 5+.

Comment: Checking if there is JDBC driver update as I use ojdbc6 (11.2.0.4) which looks like pretty up-to-date.

Comment: Upgrade to 12.2.0.1 did not help - this version has the same casting code. That is why I think Spring removal of the "nativeJdbcExtractor" feature was premature - the Oracle JDBC drivers are certified for Java 8 but their code does not use Connection.unwrap() ... not framework/pool library friendly

Comment: Checking the Spring dependency (upgrade).

Comment: Upgraded to spring-data-oracle 1.2.1-RELEASE and it also did not help as Spring is not unwrapping ... :(

Comment: Of course, the bug is still there in the source `spring-data-jdbc-ext` you need to write a custom version of `SqlArrayValue`.

Comment: I may report this bug and use the custom impl. as workaround in the meantime. Thanks Philippe for your help!

Comment: @PhilippeMarschall Where does the method `createTypeValue()` belong to? I did not get how to define it.

Comment: @LeosLiterak op was using `org.springframework.data.jdbc.support.oracle.SqlArrayValue#createTypeValue` Spring 6.1 will introduce a generic [SqlArrayValue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/support/SqlArrayValue.java), if you use Oracle you will need something like https://github.com/ferstl/spring-jdbc-oracle/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/ferstl/spring/jdbc/oracle/SqlOracleArrayValue.java