# Spring 5 replacement for CommonsDbcpNativeJdbcExtractor

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jdbc

[enter link description here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.M2/javadoc-api//org/springframework/jdbc/support/nativejdbc/SimpleNativeJdbcExtractor.html)I have a project configured with `spring boot 1.5`, I'm updating the app to `spring boot 2.XXX`, the app beans are configured in an `xml` file, part of this file contains:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/A_DATASOURCE"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dbcpNativeJdbcExtractor" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.CommonsDbcpNativeJdbcExtractor" />

    <orcl:aq-jms-connection-factory id="jmsQueueConnectionFactory"
        use-local-data-source-transaction="true" native-jdbc-extractor="dbcpNativeJdbcExtractor"
        data-source="dataSource" />
```

As you can see, there is a JMS listener connected to an Oracle queue.

The problem comes when I update to `spring 2.XXX`, I get a class not found exception, it turns out that `org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc` package has been removed from `spring-jdbc-5.0.8 jar` and [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.M2/javadoc-api//org/springframework/jdbc/support/nativejdbc/SimpleNativeJdbcExtractor.html) only says to use `apache dbcp` alternative(which I cannot find).

I know there is a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50295340/what-is-the-spring-5-jdbc-approach-when-nativejdbcextractor-is-needed), but I don't see the relationship with my problem.

Hope you can help me

Comment: That whole hierarchy doesn't exist anymore and what isn't there anymore cannot be used. Not sure where the support for the `aq-jms-connection-factory ` stands at but not sure if that is still maintained. So either don't upgrade or figure out a way to not need it (jdbc 4 can use `unwrap` to get the actual underlying connection).

Comment: Could you elaborate on the `unwrap` with jdbc4?

Comment: To get the actual underlying connection there is an `unwrap` method on the `Connection`. So something along the lines of `connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class)` should get you the actual underlying connection. However that might require an additional upgrade of the `aq-jms-connection-factory` which I'm not certain supports Spring 5.0.