# How pass VARRAY(oracle PL/SQL) param to procedure with simplejdbccall?

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, simplejdbccall

**Here is VARRAY type :**

```
CREATE TYPE NUM_ARR IS VARRAY(3) OF NUMBER(0) ;
```

**Here is Procedure**

```
PROCEDURE REGISTER_CONSENT(P_IPS_ACC_IBAN IN VARCHAR2,
                           P_IPS_BANK_BIC IN VARCHAR2,
                           P_STATUS_ID IN NUMBER,
                           P_PERMS IN NUM_ARR,
                           P_EXP_DATE IN DATE)
    IS
BEGIN

    FOR PERM_ID in P_PERMS.first ..P_PERMS.last
        LOOP
            INSERT INTO MLB_TEST.IPS_OB_CONSENT_PERMISSION(ID, CONSENT_ID, PERMISSION_ID, EXPIRATION_DATE)
            VALUES (IPS_OB_CONSENT_PERMISSION_SEQ.nextval,
                    IPS_OB_CONSENT_SEQ.currval,
                    PERM_ID,
                    P_EXP_DATE);
        END LOOP;

END;
```

**Here is simplejdbccall (java)**

```
        SimpleJdbcCall caller = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource);
    caller.withSchemaName("MLB_TEST")
            .withCatalogName("MLB_OB")
            .withProcedureName("REGISTER_CONSENT")
            .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("P_PERMS", Types.ARRAY, "NUM_ARR"));
    MapSqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue("P_IPS_ACC_IBAN", consent.getIban())
            .addValue("P_IPS_BANK_BIC", consent.getBankBic())
            .addValue("P_STATUS_ID", consent.getConsentStatusId())
            .addValue("P_PERMS", consent.getPermissionsIdList(), Types.ARRAY, "NUM_ARR")
            .addValue("P_EXP_DATE", consent.getExpirationDate());
    caller.execute(param);
```

**This is the error i get :**
*Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation: [Ljava.lang.Integer;@40f5407d
at oracle.sql.ARRAY.toARRAY(ARRAY.java:301)*

I have tried with

- Integer array Ex : new Integer[3];
- Linken list Ex : new LinkedList<>();
- int array Ex : new int[]{1,2,3};

And nothing works , i am getting same error each time .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you need some vendor specific magic to get this to work with JDBC (not specific to Spring JDBC).

Here is a class we use called OracleSqlArrayValue.  It was basically lifted from the defunct Spring JDBC extensions [library](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jdbc-ext) although it handles unwrapping the connection properly.  You will need the Oracle JDBC driver in your classpath during compile due to the import of OracleConnection.

I had additionally posted much of the below to SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60103665/tomcat-9-w-apache-dbcp-spring-5-oracle-12c-sqlarrayvalue) a while back.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.AbstractSqlTypeValue;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;

public class OracleSqlArrayValue<T> extends AbstractSqlTypeValue {
    private T[] values;
    private String defaultTypeName;

    public OracleSqlArrayValue(T[] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public OracleSqlArrayValue(T[] values, String defaultTypeName) {
        this.values = values;
        this.defaultTypeName = defaultTypeName;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createTypeValue(Connection conn, int sqlType,
            String typeName) throws SQLException {

        if (typeName == null && defaultTypeName == null) {
            throw new InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException(
                    "No type named defined. Instantiate class with default type name.");
        }

        if (!conn.isWrapperFor(OracleConnection.class)) {
            throw new InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException(
                    "Unable to unwrap OracleConnection. Ensure you are connecting to an Oracle DB.");
        }

        return conn.unwrap(OracleConnection.class).createOracleArray(
                typeName != null ? typeName : defaultTypeName, values);
    }
}
```

You would then use it like this.

```
SimpleJdbcCall caller = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource);
caller.withSchemaName("MLB_TEST")
        .withCatalogName("MLB_OB")
        .withProcedureName("REGISTER_CONSENT")
        .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("P_PERMS", Types.ARRAY, "NUM_ARR"));
MapSqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource()
        .addValue("P_IPS_ACC_IBAN", consent.getIban())
        .addValue("P_IPS_BANK_BIC", consent.getBankBic())
        .addValue("P_STATUS_ID", consent.getConsentStatusId())
        .addValue("P_PERMS", new OracleSqlArrayValue<Integer>(consent.getPermissionsIdList(), "NUM_ARR"))
        .addValue("P_EXP_DATE", consent.getExpirationDate());
caller.execute(param);
```